# マウスをタスクバー上に乗せホイールで音量変更

Tags: c#

プログラムはタスクトレイに常駐し、マウスをタスクバー上に乗せホイールすると音量が変更できるアプリを作りたいです。
検索してもタスクトレイしかでてきません。

マウスがタスクバーに入った時、ホイールできるイベントだけ教えて下さい。

Comment: [TrayVolume](http://shirosai.web.fc2.com/trayvolume/)などのフリーソフトは既存ですが、自分でもっとシンプルなものを作りたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C#による実装では[SetWindowsHookEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex)で[WH_MOUSE_LL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)のグローバルフックを行ってタスクバー上かどうかを判断するというような処理が必要になるのではないかと思います。全くお勧め出来ないのでコードは書きません。

Comment: わかりました、その方向は諦めて画面位置XYでやっていきたいと思います。

Comment: @まめたろう 画面外のマウス操作は上の方法かDirectInputじゃないと拾えないと思います

Comment: Opacityを使います。ダメなら諦めます。